# CSS - Getting link to fill entire parent <td> area

Tags: css

I'm pretty new, but have read a lot of similar SO questions.  I'm still not sure what I am missing: I'm trying to make a link clickable in the entire parent  area.  My code below makes the link the whole width of the  but not the entire height of the  area even though i use height: 100%. Please help. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    background-color: #00169d;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
}

th a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><a href='tmp'>Date</a></th>
            <th><a href='tmp'>ABCDEF</a></th>
            <th><a href='tmp'>XYZ XYZ</a></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define width/height to the anchors (a)
If you want bigger buttons, add bigger padding.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: #00169d;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

th a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

th a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><a href='tmp'>Date</a></th>
    <th><a href='tmp'>ABCDEF</a></th>
    <th><a href='tmp'>XYZ XYZ</a></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not work when my <td> elements are wider than my header / <th> elements...  In this case, the <td> link only covers part of the width of the entire area.  For example:

    <table>        
    <tr>
            <th><a href='tmp'>Date</a></th>
            <th><a href='tmp'>ABCDEF</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>VERY LONG TEXT</td>
           <td>VERY LONG TEXT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/y610mLzt/ , check with the browser dev tools inspector, and see what other styles are being applied and from where.

Comment: Thank you!  Apparently, I was using:
th a 
{ 
display: inline-block 
} 

instead of display: block...  Why does that make a difference?  Thank you!

Comment: `inline-block` acts more like `inline`, the width is as much as the text is. `block` will make the width a whole row of it's container. --- You can vote up the answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @pol As soon you have a link that is bigger than 16px, all the other links will evidence the problem not having the desired size. Is there a way to make it 100% of the parent?